# How to send custom values for Google Analytics without sending session

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently editing some code that originally written by someone else. And was using the following code for Google Analytics:

On load:

`ga('create', 'UA-000000-21');
ga('send', 'pageview');`

On some Event:

`ga('set', 'page', 'SOME-VALUE');
ga('send', 'pageview');`

But according to the new requirement I need to also send the Role of the logged in user. So that the pageviews can be classified according to user role in the Google Analytics dashboard. I have tried using custom column but failed to see any result.

Any help is appreciated. Even a general idea on how to approach this will also be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you need to send in information about the user that is logged in and what his role is? Also, the "On some Event" isn't an event, it is still sent to increment a pageview but for page 'SOME-VALUE', just as an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a new custom dimension and set the users role to that dimension. I am assuming that this is what the question is about.

Once you've set up a new dimension, look at its index and remember it. Also look at what type of scope you'd like, hit, session or visitor.

Create a function that returns the value of your user. Then when you send a page view hit with your initial load, also add the hit of the role to the push queue with:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'cd{index number}', '{value}');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('set', 'cd1', 'admin');, for example.
```

This is the general approach. If you do NOT want to add it with a page view, consider using event tracking and send it as a non-incremental value to attach it to the hit, session or user.

Also, you might want to reconsider using GA if you do not want to tie this to a session at all as per the subject.